# Is there such a thing as an argument from lack of explanation against God?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Every theory we've ever postulated to explain anything, it required a physical mechanism. For example Newton's laws describe how things interact with each other. Laws work together to produce certain effects in objects. In almost all cases, we can see how these things interact with other, either directly with our sight or other tools. In all cases, the how is detailed.

When it is said that God intervenes in certain affairs, it is simply stated that He does, but not **how**. There is no physical mechanism showing how He executes his powers, how He decides anything, how He changes certain affairs, etc. It is simply asserted. Is there an argument that goes along the lines of "because there is nothing that indicates **how** something is done it is less likely to be true"?

Answer (score 3):

> Every theory we've ever postulated to explain anything, it required a physical mechanism.

This premise is false. I can theorize, for example, that you are asking this question because you crave attention from strangers. This does not in itself imply any relevant physical mechanism at work.

> Is there an argument that goes along the lines of "because there is nothing that indicates how something is done it is less likely to be true"?

No, proving that something is the case and knowing why it is the case are clearly distinct questions. I know I am answering this pointless question right now, but yet I have absolutely no idea why. The fact that I don't know why doesn't make me doubt that it is happening.

Comment: Craving attention requires a physical process from the brain.

Comment: @thinkingman I happen to agree, but asserting that physicalism is true isn't an argument.

Comment: @BrianZ -- it is not pointless, the effort to explain philosophy is helpful to both the explainee by identifying thinking blocks they had, and explainer by helping them to articulate and structure their unarticulated views..  :-)

Comment: @Dcleve well said!

Comment: @BrianZ A successful explanation for everything happening to be physical != asserting physicalism.

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy of science is a relevant reference here.  Many physicalists reference Leibniz's theory of causation, which requires physical contact between items to translate a cause, in order to challenge non-physical causation.  However, physics in its early years showed this was not true, with Newton's gravitational force, and things like superposition in fluids.  Elizabeth of Bohemia referenced Leibniz in her famous questioning of Descartes and his assertion of a causal mind, but her objection is based on a view rejected by science.

Newton and Hume provided the grounding for science to accept a theory that matches regularities as sufficient for accepting a theory. Note, we still do not know the mechanism by which gravity works. Locke provided the conceptual basis of indirect realism, and Popper provided a more detailed justification for why we can trust science. (verified predictions made in previously untried cases).

However, within philosophy of science, a theory that proposes a mechanism IS superior to a mere regularity without one.

So, consequences from the above:

- the lack of a mechanism in God hypotheses is a weakness, but is not fatal.
- God claimants should be looking for a mechanism (need not be physical) to increase their Popperian credibility and testability
- In lieu of a mechanism, finding other extrapolated applications of a general principle could move a God claim away from appearing to be an arbitrary patch or kluge.  This is why theists in recent years have worked to find commonalities between theism and consciousness, thru an interactive spiritually dualist model.

  - Non-religiously dogmatic dualists extend this search for commonality of mechanism into the study of psi phenomenon, but the discrepancies between psi results and most religious theism make this a problematic activity for many theists.

The first bullet above suggests that if the other three are not in evidence, and one has a stronger explanatory alternative, then God theories should be considered to be less useful than a more general alternative.  This was not exactly what you suggested, but is close to it.